# Elasticsearch filter data by selected aggregations value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to search in profiles collection, each profile has firstName, middleName and lastName, gender key.

I added terms aggregation on gender which will return the count for male and female.
I am using simple search (plain text) query to find throughout the document. When I use query as query string param, query object from post body is not working. I wanted to show list of profiles return by plain text query and user can select gender filter to filter the result.

My question is where and which filter option should I use so I will get aggregation result based on query and documents after applying filter.

I tried with global aggregation but it is ignoring query. I tried with filters in aggregation but that is filtering aggregation.

For ex:

If `http://localhost:9200/profiles/_search?q=dlinx` with body

```
{
    "aggs": {
       "Gender": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "gender"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

returns aggregation result as male:10, female:15 and doc count as 25 then. After applying gender filter as male, I am expecting result as male:10, female:15, doc count as 15

Comment: You want filter only applied to query and not on aggregation, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for post filters =D

Filters which are applied only to filter hits, after the aggregations count have been "done".

[Here is the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a
>   search request, after aggregations have already been calculated

Your _search body should be something like that :

```
GET profiles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "<yourfield>": "dlinx"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Gender": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "gender": "<theselectedGender>"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `aggs` and `post_filter` should go outside of the `query` part.

Comment: Also remove the dangling comma after the match or else ES will complain about it

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying, Thanks :)